# Cond and recursivity

Tags: recursion, lisp

```
(defun mergl(l1 l2 l3)
    (cond
        ((and (null l1) (not(null l2))) l2)
        ((and (null l2) (not(null l1))) l1)
        ((and (null l1) (null l2)) l3)
        ((< (car l1) (car l2)) (setf l3 (cons (car l1) l3)) (mergl (cdr l1) l2 l3) l3)
        (t  (setf l3 (cons (car l2) l3)) (mergl l1 (cdr l2) l3) l3)
    )
)
```

The code above should take 2 lists and merge them.But for some reason,it seems like it refuses to do the recursive part.What am I missing here?(I know `append` would do this but i can't use it)

`(mergl '(1 3 5 7) '(2 4 6 8) '())` and the result was `(1)`

Comment: Are you taking a LISP class or working through a LISP book or tutorial? In LISP you want to return the merged two lists as a result of the function, not try to return the result in a 3rd argument.

Comment: @mbratch i'm taking a lisp class

Comment: In the meantime,if you can explain what exactly is not working here would be great.

Comment: I think your first two `cond` cases are incorrect. They don't merge `l1` or `l2` with `l3`. And I apologize as I had misunderstood your use of the third parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It helps to simply add a `(format t "~a ~a ~a~%" l1 l2 l3)` as the first form of your procedure; the result would be:

```
(1 3 5 7) (2 4 6 8) NIL
(3 5 7) (2 4 6 8) (1)   <-- this will be interesting later
(3 5 7) (4 6 8) (2 1)
(5 7) (4 6 8) (3 2 1)
(5 7) (6 8) (4 3 2 1)
(7) (6 8) (5 4 3 2 1)
(7) (8) (6 5 4 3 2 1)
NIL (8) (7 6 5 4 3 2 1)
(1)                     <-- oops what happened?
```

The error happens at the end; `l1` is `null` so you just return `l2` - or so you think. But the result you return is neither `l1`, `l2` or `l3` because of another bug (your code - my formatting):

```
   ((< (car l1) (car l2)) 
    (setf l3 (cons (car l1) l3))
    (mergl (cdr l1) l2 l3) 
    l3)
   (t  
    (setf l3 (cons (car l2) l3)) 
    (mergl l1 (cdr l2) l3) 
    l3)))
```

After the recursive call to `mergl` you throw away the result and, after unwinding the return stack, you end up returning the **first value you `setf` `l3` to** which happens to be `(1)` in this case. It's the first value of `l3` because every recursive call allocates a new `l3` on entering the procedure, so the first `l3` has not been modified by the later `setf` calls.

I guess this is supposed to be a *tail-recursive* procedure with an *accumulator* which should have been written like so:

```
(defun mergl (l1 l2 l3)
  (cond
   ((and (null l1) (null l2))
    (reverse l3))
   ((null l1) 
    (mergl l1 (cdr l2) (cons (car l2) l3)))
   ((null l2) 
    (mergl (cdr l1) l2 (cons (car l1) l3)))
   ((< (car l1) (car l2)) 
    (mergl (cdr l1) l2 (cons (car l1) l3)))
   (t
    (mergl l1 (cdr l2) (cons (car l2) l3)))))
```

then

```
(mergl '(1 3 5 7) '(2 4 6 8) '())
=> (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)
```

The function code is repetitive and can be simplified to:

```
(defun mergl (l1 l2 l3)
  (cond
   ((and (null l1) (null l2))
    (reverse l3))
   ((or (null l2) (and (not (null l1)) (< (car l1) (car l2))))
    (mergl (cdr l1) l2 (cons (car l1) l3)))
   (t 
    (mergl l1 (cdr l2) (cons (car l2) l3)))))
```